# how to get the size of a text with line breaks with Pillow Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to center a text inside a box using Pillow. I have followed the instructions in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67760340/how-to-add-text-in-a-textbox-to-an-image), which gives the desired result. However, if I add an line break between the words, the text does not get resized properly and it gets offcentered.

Here an example of the code without the line break:

```
title_text = "Hello World"

img = Image.new(size=(400, 300), mode='RGB')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font_path = "/content/Charlie don't surf.ttf"

# draw white rectangle 200x100 with center in 200,150
draw.rectangle((200-100, 150-50, 200+100, 150+50), fill='white')
draw.line(((0, 150), (400, 150)), 'gray')
draw.line(((200, 0), (200, 300)), 'gray')

# find font size for text `"Hello World"` to fit in rectangle 200x100
selected_size = 1
for size in range(1, 150):
    title_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(font_path, size=size)
    w, h = title_font.getsize(title_text)
    
    if w > 200 or h > 100:
        break
        
    selected_size = size
    
# draw text in center of rectangle 200x100        
title_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(font_path, size=selected_size)

draw.text((200-(w//2), 150-h//2), title_text, fill='red', font=title_font)

display(img)
```

[image: Note that the text is centered and resized as desired]

Note that the text is centered and resized as desired.

But if I change `title_text = "Hello World"` to `title_text = "Hello\nWorld"` to add an line break. I get this:

```
title_text = "Hello\nWorld"

img = Image.new(size=(400, 300), mode='RGB')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font_path = "/content/Charlie don't surf.ttf"

# draw white rectangle 200x100 with center in 200,150
draw.rectangle((200-100, 150-50, 200+100, 150+50), fill='white')
draw.line(((0, 150), (400, 150)), 'gray')
draw.line(((200, 0), (200, 300)), 'gray')

# find font size for text `"Hello World"` to fit in rectangle 200x100
selected_size = 1
for size in range(1, 150):
    title_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(font_path, size=size)
    w, h = title_font.getsize(title_text)
    
    if w > 200 or h > 100:
        break
        
    selected_size = size
    
# draw text in center of rectangle 200x100        
title_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(font_path, size=selected_size)

draw.text((200-(w//2), 150-h//2), title_text, fill='red', font=title_font)

display(img)
```

[image]

Note that with the line break, the text is not properly resized and is also not centered. Apparently the `.getsize()` method does not handle line breaks well.

I am using Pillow version 7.1.2 and running all this in a Google Colab Notebook (that is the reason why I am running `display(img)`).

What can I do to fix this issue? My end goal is to use Python to create cards for a game. Some cards will have two words and other cards will have only one word. I would like my code to be able to resize and center the text regardless the number of words.

Edit: After some test, I have noticed that `.getsize()` treats the string `"Hello\nWorld"` as a single line of text and not as two lines. My question could be: how to get the size of a text with line breaks?

Comment: Have you checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970807/center-middle-align-text-with-pil

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that answer, but it does not solve my problem for resizing and dealing with line breaks.

Comment: You can use the multiline version [`font.getsize_multiline`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getsize_multiline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. The final code looks like this:

```
title_text = "Hello\nWorld"

img = Image.new(size=(400, 300), mode='RGB')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font_path = "/content/Charlie don't surf.ttf"

# draw white rectangle 200x100 with center in 200,150
draw.rectangle((200-100, 150-50, 200+100, 150+50), fill='white')
draw.line(((0, 150), (400, 150)), 'gray')
draw.line(((200, 0), (200, 300)), 'gray')

# find font size for text `"Hello World"` to fit in rectangle 200x100
selected_size = 1
for size in range(1, 150):
    title_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(font_path, size=size)
    #w, h = title_font.getsize(title_text)
    w, h = draw.textsize(title_text, title_font)
    
    if w > 200 or h > 100:
        break
        
    selected_size = size
    
# draw text in center of rectangle 200x100        
title_font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(font_path, size=selected_size)

draw.text((200-(w//2)+5, 150-h//2), title_text, fill='red', font=title_font, align = "center")

display(img)
```

The final result is:

[image]

I have used resources I found on [this page](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2021/02/02/drawing-text-on-images-with-pillow-and-python/). More specifically I found out that you can use `draw.textsize(title_text, title_font)` to get a more precise size of the text, especially when it has line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I now have a effective approach that works like in web or app development. Simply input a text and specify padding parameters, and let the program take care of the rest. The program automatically scales the font size (inspired by user3347814) and intelligently wraps the text. Moreover, you have the flexibility to set the position by adjusting the padding.

Here it is:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def get_wrapped_text(text: str, font: ImageFont.ImageFont, line_length: int):
    lines = ['']
    for word in text.split():
        line = f'{lines[-1]} {word}'.strip()
        if font.getlength(line) <= line_length:
            lines[-1] = line
        else:
            lines.append(word)
    return '\n'.join(lines)

def imageTextGenerator(draw, text, text_spacing, font_path, padding_left, padding_top, padding_bottom, padding_right, max_width, max_height):
    # Cool Function which gets the right font size, position and multiline text
    max_font_width = max_width - padding_left - padding_right
    max_font_height = max_height - padding_top - padding_bottom
    # find right font size
    final_multiline_text = ""
    final_title_font = None
    for size in range(1, 150):
        title_font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, size=size)
        multiline_text = get_wrapped_text(text, title_font, max_font_width)
        _, _, w, h = draw.multiline_textbbox((0, 0), multiline_text, font=title_font, spacing=text_spacing)
        if w > max_font_width or h > max_font_height:
            break
        else:
            final_multiline_text = multiline_text
            final_title_font = title_font
    # find right position
    x = padding_left + (max_width - padding_left - padding_right) / 2
    y = padding_top
    return final_multiline_text, final_title_font, x, y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Provide input values
    background_image_path = "./images/image_1080_1080.jpg"
    background_image = Image.open(background_image_path)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(background_image)
    # Parameters
    text = "The Best Way To Get Started Is To Quit Talking And Begin Doing."
    quote_spacing = 12
    font_path = "./fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
    # middle Anchor! not left top
    anchor = "ma"
    padding_left = 150
    padding_top = 150
    padding_bottom = 380
    padding_right = 150
    max_width = 1080
    max_height = 1080
    # Cool Function which gets the right font size position and multiline text
    multiline_text, font, position_x, position_y = imageTextGenerator(draw, text, quote_spacing, font_path, padding_left, padding_top, padding_bottom, padding_right, max_width, max_height)
    # Draw
    draw.multiline_text(xy=(position_x, position_y), text=multiline_text, font=font, align="center", spacing=quote_spacing, fill="white", anchor=anchor)
    # Save
    background_image.save("output_image.jpg")
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a little update to the code from @user3347814

w, h = draw.textsize(title_text, title_font)

is deprecated. Just Use

_, _, w, h = draw.textbbox((0, 0), title_text, font=title_font)

instead

Answer (score 1):

I know - my answer is not 100% matching to the original question because the solution doesn't use the PIL. However it could be helpful by similar tasks.

Here is the code to get the size of multiline text:

```
# tested on Windows 10 with python 3.8.7
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width = 2000)
canvas.pack()
canvas.delete("all") # useful if you would like to repeat the part below within loop for different text/styles
text_item = canvas.create_text(10, 10, fill = "black", anchor = 'nw', font=('Times New Roman', 16, 'bold italic'), width=1990, text='Some multiline\rtext')
(x0, y0, x1, y1) = canvas.bbox(text_item)
text_size = (abs(x1-x0), abs(y1-y0))
print(text_size) # result: (133, 48)
```

**Some details about my task and why I can't use the solution based on PIL proposed here:**

I'm creating an Excel-file filled with data using *XlsxWriter* module. The usage of *win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")* is not possible because the Excel installation is not allowed on target computer. Unfortunately the *XlsxWriter autofit()* functionality is yet not precise enough, while it's important for me to minimize size of columns and rows in the table without cutting the text. So I should calculate the maximal height of cells in each row and maximal width of cells in each column and set the sizes "manually".

Because the *XlsxWriter* has not interface to read cells content/format after it was added (and workaround with accessing of data indirectly [was not recommended for usage by author of XlsxWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865195/python-xlsxwriter-extract-value-from-cell#comment111848986_63251349)) - I should collect the information during adding it to the table. I've created a wrapper for *sheet.write()*, which additionally stores font-style and cell-content.

Next step was to calculate the cell size based on its content & style.
I've found solution for PIL proposed here and tried it. Unfortunately in my case **the text rendered with PIL was significantly smaller** than same text rendered by Excel or Paint using the same ttf-font/style. Correspondingly the size calculated with PIL was smaller than really needed for proper representation in Excel.

Then I've tried the rendering results with *freetype-py* and *PILasOPENCV* - it was a bit better, but still not perfect (by all those tests I've used Arial.ttf with size = 8).

The test with *tkinter* (see code above) has shown the exact match as in Excel or Paint, therefore I decide to use it for "manual autofit" by Excel-files.

***Note:*** because the real size of text rendered with PIL differs from size of text rendered with tkinter - you should select the suitable way to get the text size based on your case (i.e. depending on which engine will render the text in your system).